# Rails convert collection_select to text input with autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I currently have a `f.collection_select` in my rails app.
What is the best way to convert this into a text input box with autocomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go http://github.com/rails/auto_complete

Comment: Update the link  please, It is broken.

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association also teaches you how to do this too with that plugin.